# How to slice by index object property value which is a string?

Tags: javascript, slice

I have an object:

```
const text = {
    type: 'text',
    content: "some text",
};
```

I need slice value of `content` property by index, for example, if I have `index = 4` then `console.log(text.content)` should print:

> "some"

It looks like this code doesn't work:

```
text.content.slice(0, index);
```

I still have

> "some text"

on `console.log(text.content)`.

What have I misunderstood?

Comment: Use ```text.content.substr(0, index);``` instead of slice.

Comment: Some array operators work on strings but not all of them. Use substr

Comment: @SajeebAhamed, `substr` is deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr . It is recommended to use `substring`. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you. It's my bad. I've just meant to use substring.

Comment: @SajeebAhamed, I have just tried to replace `splice` to `substring` but it still doesn't work. But I use vue, so it could be also an issue with vue reactivity.

Comment: If it's related to vue then you should share the vue code to understand the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are immutable. you need an assignment to the property with the new substring.

```js
const
    text = { type: 'text', content: "some text" },
    index = 4;
    
text.content = text.content.slice(0, index); // assignment of substring

console.log(text.content);
```

Comment: I made and assignment but without success. I use also vue and it could be an issue with vue reactivity.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at string.substring():

https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/string/substring

There you go:

`text.content.substring(0, index)`

Comment: It works now with `slice` but with assignment. Thank you for pointing to another option for `slice`.

Answer (score 1):

Slice doesn't mutate the string. So if you instead console.log(text.content.slice(0, index)), you will see the result you are looking for.

Comment: You are right about `Slice doesn't mutate the string`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`strings are immutable`. You need to assign the `sliced` value back to `content`

```js
const text = {
    type: 'text',
    content: "some text",
};
const index=4;
text.content=text.content.slice(0,index)
console.log(text)
```

`slice` works fine

Comment: I have done some mistake with assignment and it didn't work for me. Now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Per specification ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)):

> The slice() method extracts a section of a string and returns it as a
>   new string, without modifying the original string.

```js
const text = {
    type: 'text',
    content: "some text",
};

const index = 4;
const result = text.content.slice(0, index);

console.log(text.content); // some text
console.log(result); // some

text.content = result;
console.log(text.content); // some
```

Comment: I have done some mistake with assignment and it didn't work for me. Now it works. Thank you!